# How to trigger parametrized Jenkins Job using command line?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Recently, we have implemented a parametrized Jenkins Pipeline Job to trigger our Selenium TestCases. We want to trigger the build using CLI (in our case 'Command Prompt'). But unfortunately we are unable to send any parameter values using CLI. The Job is getting triggered with default values only.

We tried below way but job is getting trigger always with first test case (default value) in the TestCase choice dropdown:

```
curl -I https://<jenkinsURL>/job/<jobName>/buildWithParameters?token=<tokenName>&TestCase=<TCName>
```

where,
TestCase is Choice Parameter to select a desired test case to execute.

Anybody is having any idea, please help me out.

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: Can you share the `parameters` part of your pipeline?

Comment: @MaratC - We are trying to pass a Test Case as a parameter to a parametrized Jenkins build using CLI.  All these test cases are listed in **'TestCase'** parameter, which is of type 'Choice' (dropdown). We have total of 10 test cases present in the dropdown and while triggering Jenkins Build using CLI, we wanted to pass any one of the testcase listed in the dropdown.